# using convertEmptyStringsToNull=false only on specific fields?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a domain class, which has a composite unique-constraint where some fields are defined "not null".

In this domain class with these fields, I would like to set

```
convertEmptyStringToNull = false
```

but only for these 2 fields in this domain-class.

The reason is, that the unique-constraint should work that it take all fields of the constraint into account not only, if all fields are filled...

Is that is somehow possible?

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be, to use the BindUsing annotation from Grails >= 2.3

Example:

```
@BindUsing({ obj, source -> source['parName2'].trim() })
String parName2
```

This enables only the trim() function on the field an suppresses the stringToNull functionality.

Here's [Grails Jira Ticket](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10142) with the same problem.
and a discussion here [Grails User List](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Grails-2-3-Data-Binding-String-Trimming-And-Null-Conversions-td4645255.html)

Only problem I have, but it seems not a problem with the solution is, that the duplicate error message mentions now only the first attribute in the composite unique constraint...